# How to print the dictionary key with the maximum length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
x = {'0': 'test1', 
     '1': 'test2', 
     '98hbu98hg7': 'test4', 
     '21292392392494223423432423': 'test3'}

print(max(x.keys()))
```

Prints out:

```
98hbu98hg7
```

instead of:

```
21292392392494223423432423
```

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) returns the largest item by **comparison**. Meaning, using `<`. And since your keys are strings, `'98hbu98hg7'` is printed because it is lexicographically the largest (since `9` comes after `2`).

You can specify a different ordering function by using the `key` keyword argument:

```py
x = {'0': 'test1', '1': 'test2', '98hbu98hg7': 'test4', '21292392392494223423432423': 'test3'}

print(max(x.keys(), key=len))
```

And this prints:

```
21292392392494223423432423
```